# True or false: if $f'(c)<0$, then $f$ is concave down at $x=c$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I determine the following statement is true or false?

If $f'(c)<0$, then $f$ is concave down at $x=c$ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Also, I need a definition.  I know concave down on an interval.  But what is concave down at a point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the *sign* of $f'(c)$ determines only if a function is increasing if $f'(c) > 0$, decreasing if $f'(c)\lt 0$, or neither, e.g., when $f'(c) = 0$. at point $x = c$. So the first derivative evaluated at a point $c$ tells us about the slope of the line tangent to the graph of the function at the point where $x = c$. It tells us nothing about the concavity of the function.

The ***second derivative***, on the other hand, gives us information about the concavity of a function at any given point.

The statement you are given is asserting that based on the value of $f'(c)$ alone, you can determine the concavity of a function. *And this is not true*, as Zev's example shows: He has included the graph of a quadratic function $f$ that is ***concave-up***, and such that the first derivative $f'(x)$ evaluated at some $c$ gives $f'(c) < 0$.

Comment: Thanks now I can understand.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the answer to all. I really appreciate your help. I don't have good mathematic foundation. This is the reason I'm trying to teach my self calculus. Although sometimes I feel lost. So any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Consider this picture:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what to consider?

Comment: Do you understand what $f'(c)$ means? Do you understand what "concave down" means?

Comment: Well not really. I'm starting to study calculus now. And I'm trying to figure out what things are.

Comment: I'm trying to self teach calculus.